# How to bind multiple pairs of value fields generated by javascript on button click into a single model property

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working on forms in asp .net core application.

I'm trying to collect a list of values pairwise, which means when a user clicks on a button two fields would be generated and the user would fill those two values and submits it.
Users can click on the same button and get two more fields generated and fill those too based on the need.
above mentioned functionality is presented below.

```js
function add_fields() {
  document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += '<br/><br/>'+'value 1 : <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" /> <br/>'+
        'value 2: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" />'+'<br/><br/>'
}
```

```html
<div id="room_fileds">
    <div class="content" id="wrapper"> 
       value 1 : <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" /> <br/>
        value 2: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" /><br/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />
</div>
```

the target is to somehow bind it and to create a JObject and save it as a **string** in the database.

I can take care of converting it into JObject and storing it but i need to get it into a variable List on which I'll iterate and convert it into JObject.

I'm not sure on what to keep in the model. For now I have that filed as below.

```
public class TestBind
{
    public List<subnets> pairvalues { get; set; }
}
public class subnets
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm thinking that it would work this way but I'm not sure.

please suggest me some ideas on how to implement it. thanks in advance. Each attempt is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name in the Input tag should be modified to bind the model.You can refer to this following step.

In index.cshtml

```
 <form action="/home/get" method="get">
        <div id="room_fileds">
            <div class="content" id="wrapper">
                value 1 : <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="pairvalues[0].value1" value="" /> <br />
                value 2: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="pairvalues[0].value2" value="" /><br />
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="sub" />
    </form>
@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        var i=1
        function add_fields() {
            document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += '<br/><br/>' + 'value 1 : <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="pairvalues[' + i +'].value1" value="" /> <br/>' +
                'value 2: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="pairvalues[' + i +'].value2" value="" />' + '<br/><br/>'
            i++
        }
    </script>
}
```

Here is the action.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public IActionResult get(TestBind testBind)
        {
            return Json(testBind);
        }
}
```

Then, it will get the data from that form.
[image]

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you so much